# How to configure ClaimTransformer for CoreWCF with TCP endpoints?

Tags: windows-authentication, corewcf

Current WCF application has this ClaimsTransformer implementation. Is there a way to Configure/Implement the same in CoreWCF?

Configuration

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="ClaimsTransformer, ClaimsTransformerLibrary" />
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

And ClaimsTransformer adds some custom claims based on User roles.

```
 public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
 {
     public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
     {
         // claims transformation logic     

         return Task.FromResult(principal);
     }
 }
```

Added the ClaimsTransformer as a Middleware, but TransformAsync is not getting called on any request.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Other service configurations


       services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
    }
}
```